# What are some good pure JavaScript tutorial and references?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to brush up my JavaScript with a view to tackling Node.js.  What are some good references that deal purely with the language and bypass DOM, CSS and HTML?

Comment: The ECMAScript specification is not the most exciting thing to read, but it is incredibly helpful: http://es5.github.com/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: Anything but w3schools. Seriously, keep away from that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html).

Answer (score 2):

JS Design Patterns from Addy Osmani

http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Answer (score 1):

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @TimWolla Everyone answered like I did .. so why pick on me?

Comment: Yours is simply link with a abbreviation as title. You, in my opinion, could write Microsoft Developer Network as well.

Comment: @TimWolla I will never write that! :)

Comment: Oops. Fail. But imo your Answer is better now.

Answer (score 0):

Really good reference: http://dochub.io/#javascript/